# Akai MPC Bootscreen (Splash Screen)

Tags: splash-screen, mpc

I wanted to change the boot screen or splash screen of an MPC X, I got SSH access and I removed the files from the partitions (mmcblk0p4 {splash} / mmcblk0p5 {recoverysplash}) but I got stuck.

Image format in MPCX: RAW BRGA, width: 800 height: 1200 32 bits colors depth

The thing is that I wanted to take a backup of the original images just in case or to modify them and I can't.

I have not yet created a 0 image with said format although I have the necessary software. (I'll update the post when I do)

Has anyone made any attempt or can enlighten me on this matter.

Thanks in advance.